# AutoPostBack doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, autopostback

i am trying to learn how to use autopostback, so i wrote this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="check" ID="Tz"></asp:TextBox>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void check(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("checked");
}
```

i assumed that when i would trigger the autopostback by changing the text in the textbox, i'll see checked written on the screen, but nothing happaned.

there was a window that poped up and said that there is an unhandled exception, in addion it showed me this while i was running the debugger:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['register'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.register;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

the line theForm.submit(); was marked.

Comment: What was the error displayed to you - can you post the error message? Also - is your textbox inside of UpdatePanel?

Comment: the textbox isn't inside of UpdatePanel. it is inside a form tags <form></form>

Answer (score 2):

This code should work.

The only thing I can think of is that you may be expecting the autopostback to trigger when you type something in the textbox but it is actually only fired when the textbox loses focus like after you click anywhere outside of the textbox.

Comment: As octurnal suggested, this should work, and the only way this would work, is to get your focus out of the textbox after the text change, and you will see the autopostback in effect.  Instead of writing out to the page, place a label and set the text property to "changed" in your text_changed event.

Comment: i tried what you said and placed a label : <label id="ch" runat="server"></label> and in the code behind i wrote this.ch.innerText="checked"; but when the text box loses focus it still does the same error

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.
all i had to do was change the id of the submit button from submit to something else.

Comment: @Sajeetharan -- Actually, this does provide an answer. The error was having the id or name of `submit` which overrides the form's `submit` method.  Changing name fixes the problem.  It is a weird, hard-to-find bug.